# jQuery submit() is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, google-chrome

I am trying to trigger the submit of a form from a link outside the form (not the submit button).

Here is the basics of the form:

```
<form action="/Hospice/TabPatientTrackingPost" id="formTabPatientTrackingPost" method="post">

    [a big form with lots of inputs]

    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-brand" id="btnSave" name="btnSave">Save</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-brand" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is what the link looks like:

```
<a href="/Hospice/TabLiving/1" onclick="triggerSave();">Living</a></li>
```

JS Function:

```
 function triggerSave() {
    alert("triggerSave test alert");
    $("#formTabPatientTrackingPost").submit(); 
}
```

But, the code `$("#formTabPatientTrackingPost").submit();` is not causing the form to post the submit.

The `alert("triggerSave test alert");` is firing, but the form is not submitting.

It works fine if I just click the Save button.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Were any errors given in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console, and triggerSave() is getting called in the `onclick` of the link.

Comment: Is `triggerSave()` available on the `window`?

Comment: Is there any code specified for the Submit event in the form?

$('#form').submit(function(){...});

Comment: I see everyone's jsfiddle below works, but there is something wrong with mine that is preventing .submit() and .trigger('click') from working. I'll keep working on it and see what I can figure out.  thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I worked on this more, I realized the problem was only occurring in Chrome.  Everything worked in Firefox and IE (yeah, who would have guessed).

Then, that led me to this post: [JQuery submit not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418738/jquery-submit-not-working-in-chrome)

So, my final solution was to use an AJAX POST to get this working:

```
    triggerSave = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Hospice/TabPatientTrackingPost',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#formTabPatientTrackingPost').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you to everyone that helped! +1 for all the useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you have posted, this works fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/jFYN2/

```
triggerSave();
```

I would check to make sure you're including the right version of jQuery.

Also verify that you do not have any syntax issues in the [a big form with lots of inputs]

Comment: Also check that the script is being executed when the document loads! `$(document).ready(function(){/*...*/})`

Answer (score 2):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/8rLGN/2/

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("triggerSave test alert");
    $("#btnSave").trigger('click'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure your function is available globally when calling functions from the `onclick` attribute, try:

```
triggerSave = function() {
    alert("triggerSave test alert");
    $("#formTabPatientTrackingPost").submit();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/STDD3/)

Comment: The `alert` is getting called, so it seems that part is working.

Comment: @L_7337 check the demo the form does get submitted as well.